# Grails checkbox always false

Tags: grails

First time working wtih checkboxes in Grails. What I want the checkbox to do is simply set a boolean variable to true if checked.

From the form.gsp:

```
 <div class="form-group  col-md-12 ${hasErrors(bean: apiInstance, field: 'oneWay', 'error')} ">
 <label for="oneWay">
     <g:message code="api.oneway.label" default="One Way" />
 </label>
 <g:checkBox name="oneWay " value="true" checked="${apiInstance?.oneWay == 'true'}"/>
 </div>
```

In my domain class I have this defined:

```
 Boolean oneWay = false
```

And in the service that is called from the controller I check the status of oneWay:

```
    if (apiInstance.oneWay == true) {
        log.info("One way flag is set.")
    } else {
        log.info("One way flag is not set.")
    }
```

It's always false even when I check the checkbox. What act of stupidity am I committing? :D

Comment: `${apiInstance?.oneWay == true}` or simply `${apiInstance?.oneWay}`

Comment: @SaschaFrinken that is called `String-driven development`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use the value and checked attributes, just use value like:

```
<g:checkBox name="oneWay " value="${apiInstance?.oneWay}" />
```